# Error in ios8 app- SearchBar is searching but not displaying data on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar

I am trying to make an ios app on xcode by following this - http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/. When I type  in search bar everything works in console but output is not getting displayed on the screen

```
@interface AllUseraStatusViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *statusText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *statusTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *statusUserName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *statusList;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allStatusLists;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *searchResults;
@property(strong,nonatomic) PFObject *object;
@end

@implementation AllUseraStatusViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Status"];
    [query includeKey:@"user"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        // 3
        if (!error){
            self.statusList = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            // 4
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error userInfo][@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }];


}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }else{
        return [self.statusList count];
    }

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier= @"AllUsersStatusCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        self.object =[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        NSLog(@"THIS IS object %@",self.object); 
    }else{
        self.object =[self.statusList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    }
    NSLog(@"THIS IS objectttt %@",self.object); <--this prints correct status in console
    UILabel *statusText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [statusText setText:[self.object objectForKey:@"status"]];
    NSLog(@"THIS IS objectttt %@",statusText);<--but this prints null in console

    UILabel *statusTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    [statusTime setText:[[self.object createdAt] description]];

    UILabel *statusUserName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    PFUser *userName = [self.object objectForKey:@"user"];
    [statusUserName setText:userName.username];

    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        UserProfileViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        PFObject *object = [self.statusList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        vc.statusObject=object;
    }
}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller      shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForTextSearch:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

-(void)filterContentForTextSearch:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status contains[c] %@",searchText];
    NSLog(@"THIS IS %@",resultPredicate);
    self.searchResults = [self.statusList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"THIS IS THE %@", self.searchResults);
}

@end
```

MAKING THE ERROR MORE CLEAR

This is the error in the above code

```
 NSLog(@"THIS IS object %@",self.object);// this prints correct object 
 UILabel *statusText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100]; 
 [statusText setText:[self.object objectForKey:@"status"]]; 
 NSLog(@".....THIS IS objectt %@",statusText.text);// it prints null on console 
 NSLog(@".....THIS IS objectttt %@",[self.object objectForKey:@"status"]);// this prints correct o/p
```

Comment: Did you add to your searchbardelegate [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

Comment: I m a newbie, please tell me where shall i include this line of code?

Comment: Inside of -(BOOL)searchDisplayController

Comment: I tried that in searchDisplayController. But it didnt help. I have edited the question to make the errors more clear which I found. please have a look

Comment: But this is printing correct o/p on console--> NSLog(@".....THIS IS objectttt %@",[self.object objectForKey:@"status"]); Problem is dat it is not setting in UILabel statusText. How can I set that?

Comment: You can try for setting UILabel text -- [statusText setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.object objectForKey:@"status"]];

Comment: Still its(NSLog(@".....THIS IS objectt %@",statusText.text);) printing null :(